# Spring batch vs Kafka Streams

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing, apache-kafka-streams

I have to implement a solution that consists of processing a large amount of data by applying business requirement rules. The input and the output will be a file.

I haven't been using Kafka before, I am wondering if I can use Kafka streams to process these rules or use spring batch combined with Kafka streams.
Is there any other frameworks/technologies that can be used in Java?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Streams is a stream processing solution; what you're talking about is more of a batch workload. The difficulties you will encounter using KStreams are:

1. Kafka Streams doesn't have a good way of working with files as input and output.
2. In Stream Processing, there's no real concept of "beginning" and "end," whereas I gather from the nature of your question that you do indeed have a beginning and end in your use-case.

As such I would recommend another batch solution.